# Writing and using your own functions - basics

Tags: python

Your task is to write and test a function which takes two arguments (a year and a month) and returns the number of days for the given month/year pair (yes, we know that only February is sensitive to the year value, but we want our function to be universal).  Now, convince the function to return None if its arguments don't make sense.

Use a list filled with the months' lengths. You can create it inside the function - this trick will significantly shorten the code.

I have got the code down but not the 'none' part. Can someone help me with this?

```
def IsYearLeap(year):
    if (year%4==0):
        return True
    if (year%4!=0):
        return False

def DaysInMonth(year,month):
    if month in {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12}:
        return 31

    elif month==2:
        if IsYearLeap(year):
            return 29
        else:
            return 28
    elif month in {4,6,8,9,11}:
        return 30
    else:
        return none

 testyears = [1900, 2000, 2016, 1987,2019]
 testmonths = [ 2, 2, 1, 11,4]
 testresults = [28, 29, 31, 30,33]
 for i in range(len(testyears)):
    yr = testyears[i]
    mo = testmonths[i]
    print(yr,mo,"->",end="")
    result = DaysInMonth(yr,mo)
    if result == testresults[i]:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("Failed")
```

Comment: Python is case sensitive so it must be `None`.

Comment: We don't like to do homework. Also, this question shows no research effort.

Comment: @MilkyWay90 The code is nearly complete and the question only refers to a minor problem which can be overlooked easily by a beginner. This is perfectly on topic in my opinion.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I see, changed my vote

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have rather made a simple mistake. If you are not used the case-sensitive programming languages or have no experience in programming languages, this is understandable.

The keyword `None` is being misspelled as the undefined word `none`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your testresults is wrong. February of 1900 should be 29 days also April of 2019 30 days. Also its None instead none. Another things also its better to using list on months list so you could using [1, 3, 5, 7, ...] instead {1, 3, 5, 7, ...}.

Also from your test cases you won't got None, in case you want check this case you could check with month = 13, and you will cover this case

Answer (score 0):

As a further comment to the other good answers to this question, the correct rule for leap years should be something like:

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    """ is it a leap year?
    >>> is_leap_year(1984)
    True

    >>> is_leap_year(1985)
    False

    >>> is_leap_year(1900)
    False

    >>> is_leap_year(2000)
    True
    """
    return (year % 4 == 0 and 
            (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0))
```

Similarly, the test cases need to be clear that 1900 was not a leap year, 2000 was. I recommend writing a separate set of test cases for `is_leap_year`. Ultimately, in production code, you will be better off to use one of the many time/date libraries. The comments that I've provided make use of [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html?highlight=doctest#module-doctest) to provide this unit test quickly.

Answer (score 0):

A function which does not explicitly `return` anything implicitly returns `None`.

In addition to the spelling error (`none` vs `None`) you are using this by accident here:

```py
def IsYearLeap(year):
    if (year%4==0):
        return True
    if (year%4!=0):
        return False
```

Can you see what will happen if neither of the conditions is true? It won't `return` either `False` or `True`, which presumably the caller expects. (Though if you check whether `None == True` you will get `False`, and `not None` is `True`, so you won't get a syntax error, just a result which might be different from what you expect - the worst kind of bug!)

Answer (score 0):

```
def IsYearLeap(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 & (year % 400 == 0 | year % 100 != 0)
def DaysInMonth(year,month):
     if month in [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]:
        return 31
     elif month==2:
        if IsYearLeap(year):
            return 29
        else:
            return 28
     elif month in [4,6,8,9,11]:
        return 30
     else:
        return None
#

testYears = [1900, 2000, 2016, 1987]
testMonths = [2, 2, 1, 11]
testResults = [28, 29, 31, 30]
for i in range(len(testYears)):
    yr = testYears[i]
    mo = testMonths[i]
    print(yr, mo, "->", end="")
    result = DaysInMonth(yr, mo)
    if result == testResults[i]:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("Failed")
```

Comment: Couple of things: you use binary instead of logical operators (use `and`/`or` instead of `&`/`|`). `for i in range(len...` is bad style, use `for yr, mo in zip(testYears, testMonths)` instead. Finally, try to use pep-8 style variables. Also, if you answering a question, please add some comments to show why the original solution failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_year_leap(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0


def days_in_month(year, month):
    days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if type(year) != int or year < 1582 or\
    type(month) != int or month < 1 or month > 12:
        return None
    elif is_year_leap(year):
        del days[1]
        days.insert(1, 29)
    return days[month - 1]


test_years = [1900, 2000, 2016, 1987]
test_months = [2, 2, 1, 11]
test_results = [28, 29, 31, 30]
for i in range(len(test_years)):
    yr = test_years[i]
    mo = test_months[i]
    print(yr, mo, "->", end="")
    result = days_in_month(yr, mo)
    if result == test_results[i]:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("Failed")
```

Answer (score 0):

A few minor remarks:

- You should remove the duplicate 8th month (August is listed for 30 and 31 days),
- Better replace brackets {} with the list [],
- Replace none with None (Python is case-sensitive, None is the keyword),
- Add one more condition for a leap year:

(year % 400 == 0) and (year % 100 == 0) -> return True

(year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0) -> return True